# Passing Multiple Db contexts by dependency injection in .net core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am writing a utility to update settings in each of our environments in .NET 6.0, using Blazor Wasm (which really shouldn't matter here...).

I have three databases, representing 3 different environments (its the same database in 3 places).

I configure my contexts as follows

```cs
var devConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevelopmentServer");
var qaConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("QAServer");
var prodConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProdServer");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DockDevContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(devConnectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DockQaContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(qaConnectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DockProdContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(prodConnectionString));
```

And my service looks like:

```
public PricingRepository(
    DockDevContext dockDevContext,
    DockQaContext dockQaContext,
    DockProdContext dockProdContext,
    IOptions<CosmosOptions> options)
{
    _dockDevContext = dockDevContext;
    _dockQaContext = dockQaContext;
    _dockProdContext = dockProdContext;
    _options = options.Value;
}
```

Ignore the cosmos options...

My Database contexts all look like:

```cs
public class DockDevContext : BaseContext
{
    public DockDevContext(DbContextOptions<DockDevContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And all 3 inherit from basecontext:

```
public class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserMapping>? UserMappings { get; set; }
    public BaseContext(DbContextOptions options ):base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

My update routine looks like:

```cs
private void AddCustomerNumberMapping<TContext>(
    TContext context,
    MsaPricing msaPricing, 
    bool isProd = false) 
    where TContext : BaseContext
{
    var mapping = new UserMapping
    {
        UserId = isProd ? ProdUserId : NonProdUserId,
        CustomerNumber = long.Parse(msaPricing.CustomerNumber)
    };

    var existingMapping = context.UserMappings? 
        .Where(map => mapping.UserId == map.UserId &&
            mapping.CustomerNumber == map.CustomerNumber);

    context.UserMappings?.Add(mapping);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I run this the first time with contextA, it works
When i run this with context B it fails, saying its been disposed.

Comment: i have tried ripping out the Generic function and replacing it with ones that used the typed contexts directly, but it made no difference

Comment: _"When I run this the first time with contextA, it works When i run this with context B it fails, saying its been disposed."_ What does that mean? What is contextA and context B? Do you really access all three databases at the same time?

Comment: Are you certain that the problem isn't a missing `await`? eg the service scope was disposed before accessing context B.

Comment: Also, rather than having 3 fixed contexts, you can override `OnConfiguring` to get the connection string in a different way.

Comment: Jasen, Context A is aa database context for one database, and b for another.  I do need to access all 3 at the same time.  THanks!

Comment: Please show us a more complete example so that others can reproduce this error.